# How to load iframe content correctly in to <div in main page (same domain iframe)?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I got an ifram that has many links in it and i am trying to copy those link correctly to my main page. My current code copy the links incorectly .For example if the
actual hyper link is like this in iframe:

```
<a href="./ok/doit.php"> 5 </a>
```

after coping it in to main page the hyper links become like this :

```
http://ok.mysite24.com/spring/./ok/doit.php
```

so after clicking to those links from within my main page i go to dead links instead of actual links. is there away to fix this problem by copying iframe content correctly or should i modify my iframe content ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getFrameContents(){
   var iFrame =  document.getElementById('myframe');
   var iFrameBody;
   if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
   { // FF
     iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   }
   else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
   { // IE
     iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   }
 alert(iFrameBody.innerHTML);

document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = iFrameBody.innerHTML

 }
</script>

<iframe id ='myframe' src='http://www.mysite.com/ok.php'></iframe>

<div id="response"> 
    <p><a href="#" onMouseDown="getFrameContents()">getFrameContents! </a></p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you want to resolve one relative address to the iframe's source address, which may also be relative. Psuedo code (ish):k

```
function resolveAddress(source, link) {
   if(link.indexOf("../") == 0) {
       index--; // go up one directory .//
       return resolveAddress(source.substr(0,source.lastIndexOf("/")-1),
                      link.substr(1, link.length-1)); 
   }
   else if(link.indexOf("./") == 0) {
       // reduce to current directory ./
       return resolveAddress(source.substr(0,source.lastIndexOf("/"),
                      link.substr(2, link.length-1));
   }
   return source + link;
}      

frame_src = "http://www.mysite.com/ok.php"
link = "./ok/doit.php";

resolveAddress(frame_src, link);
//=> "http://www.mysite.com/ok/doit.php"
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But how to replace all those dynamic links before output them to main page? could you tell me how i can call your function from within my code ? furthermore why your passing full incorrect url to the escpaePath function? shouldn't we only pass http://ok.mysite24.com/spring part only to escapePath function ?

Comment: document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = escapePath(iFrameBody.innerHTML);

Answer (score 1):

Before retrieving the innerHTML loop over all links and replace their DOM-href-attribute with their JS-href-property.  This will turn the href-attributes into absolute URIs.

```
//clone the body to keep the original untouched
iFrameBody = iFrameBody.cloneNode(true);

var links = iFrameBody.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < iFrameBody.getElementsByTagName('a').length; ++i) {
    if (links[i].hasAttribute('href')) {
        links[i].setAttribute('href', links[i].href);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean i should modify my iframe php content from within php to full path? but i don't want to use full path!

Comment: No, the body of the iFrame is still a node, you can modify it with javascript.  You find here houndreds of topics where you can read that it's a bad practice to parse documents with string methods(e.g. with PHP). Doing it with JS isn't much better, but parsing a document or Node with DOM-methods is a good approach. Watch a Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MSAkC/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MSAkC/)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. But i want clickable links in main page just like iframe! in your demo you just posted the correct html code of links!

Comment: I didn't post it, it's the result of the conversion done by javascript. I choosed to print the source for demonstration-purposes, of course you can use the result also with innerHTML